# Craft directory 403 Access Forbidden with XAMPP

Tags: install, installation, environments

I've been using xampp for a long time and have never encountered a 403 error. I have many projects in my xampp/htdocs/ folder, none of them have ever had any problems until now. **I have the craft files in a /craft folder inside htdocs but any time I try to visit files within this directory I am met with the 403 error.**

I have been searching a solution for hours now, I edited **httpd-vhosts.conf** with the following but it didn't help:

```
<Directory "C:/xampp/xampp/craft/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Again, no other folders within my htdocs directory has ever had any 403 errors. Anyone got a clue as to what is causing this and how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

That’s a good thing - you definitely **don’t** want to allow direct HTTP traffic to your craft/ folder, as people would be able to access your config settings, license key, and plenty of other sensitive data.

There’s a .htaccess file inside your craft/ folder with `Deny from all` in it, which is what is responsible for that 403 error you’re getting. Keep it in there!